# How to fix "package ‘RcmdrMisc’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)" on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r

I am trying to run rcommander in Rstudio Version 1.2.5001, (I am on Ubuntu 18.04) when I launch
library(Rcmdr)

I get:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RcmdrMisc’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 shared object ‘haven.so’ not found
Error: package ‘RcmdrMisc’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
S3 methods ‘[.haven_labelled’, ‘[.haven_labelled_spss’, ‘as.data.frame.haven_labelled’, ‘as_factor.data.frame’, ‘as_factor.haven_labelled’, ‘as_factor.labelled’, ‘format.pillar_shaft_haven_labelled_chr’, ‘format.pillar_shaft_haven_labelled_num’, ‘is.na.haven_labelled_spss’, ‘print.haven_labelled’, ‘print.haven_labelled_spss’, ‘type_sum.haven_labelled’, ‘zap_formats.data.frame’, ‘zap_formats.default’, ‘zap_label.data.frame’, ‘zap_label.default’, ‘zap_labels.data.frame’, ‘zap_labels.default’, ‘zap_labels.haven_labelled’, ‘zap_labels.haven_labelled_spss’, ‘zap_missing.data.frame’, ‘zap_missing.default’, ‘zap_missing.haven_labelled’, ‘zap_missing.haven_labelled_spss’, ‘zap_widths.data.frame’, ‘zap_widths.default’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found
```

trying install.packages("RcmdrMisc") I get:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/marco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RcmdrMisc’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)
```

However If i try to install r-cran-rcmdrmisc (1.0-7-1) on my system with apt-get I get:

```
r-cran-rcmdrmisc is already the newest version (1.0-7-1).
```

I don't know what to do to fix the issue and run rcommander :(
Help?

Comment: Is this the full error message? I liike like some linux library is missing....

Comment: Try updating your R version (from 3.4.4 to > 3.5.0).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your error message is actually from package `haven`.  Overall, you are a bit lost between packages from Ubuntu, and packages from R/CRAN.  There *is* a solution:  read this [README](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) carefully.  It will a) allow you to use `apt` to get a current R (now 3.6.1) for your system and b) also get 4000+ CRAN packages via apt.  Come to the r-sig-debian list for more help, or search old questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. I was successfully able to update R (I think..) however now when I run library(Rcmdr)

Loading required package: splines
Loading required package: RcmdrMisc
Loading required package: car
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’ in readRDS(pfile):
 cannot read workspace version 3 written by R 3.6.1; need R 3.5.0 or newer
Error: package ‘car’ could not be loaded

After restarting again Rstudio I got:

Error in readRDS(file) : 
  cannot read workspace version 3 written by R 3.6.1; need R 3.5.0 or newer

> install.packages("rcmdr")
>   Installing package into ‘/home/marco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘rcmdr’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)

I am puzzled :/